# Make Apache2.4 send a 403 when incorrect login details are entered instead of the browser asking again

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, apache2, login, http-status-code-403

I'm using .htaccess to password protect a file on my webserver. If incorrect login details are entered then the browser just shows the login box again. How can I make the browser send a 403 Forbidden instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer when the user use incorrect password is 401, instead when the user use correct credentials but isn't allowed the correct response is 403.

From [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.2):

> **401 Unauthorized**: "The request requires user authentication. The response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field ([section 14.47](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.47)) containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource. The client MAY repeat the request with a suitable Authorization header field ([section 14.8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.8)). If the request already included Authorization credentials, then the 401 response indicates that authorization has been refused for those credentials..."

From [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3):

> **403 Forbidden**: "...The server understood the request, but is refusing to authorize it..."

Comment: To repeat: it is your **browser** who decides to give up after so-and-so-many failed attempts: The first request is without any credentials and gets a 401, thus making the browser ask you for credentials. If the next request is with credentials, but these are bad, the correct reply is still 401, which *may* cause the browser to ask you again for creds. This repeats until the browser decides you tried too often (the server does no bookkeeping). -- You *might* bend the rules and return 403 when creds are given but wrong. However, this will break if different creds are needed for nested folders